# laravel pagination manipulate into data

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5.7

I want add list of column having specific value e.g 1 in new column i.e field in every row in pagination. but i am not getting any column in simple foreach, as we get in get() call call in laravel.

```
$user = ToolData::where('sku','=',$q)->orWhere('asin','=',$q)->orWhere('location','=',$q)->paginate(10);
foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
  $arrVal = (array)$value;
  $keys = array_keys($arrVal, 1);
  $value->mgm = implode(', ', $keys);
}
```

i was doing something like this... i know i am doing something wrong here but help me how can i do things here?

Comment: Where's you use your `$arrVal` variable? Where's you define your `$keys` variable?

Comment: post has been edited. @OlegNurutdinov

Comment: Well, did you try to debug this part of code to make sure your variables has values you expected? P.S. you can use `dd($var);` or `dump(var);` for example.

Comment: yes... it shows all columns in attributes field. but when `dd($value->attributes);`  it shows `null`